# Temporarily granting elevated administrator privileges to ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net, security, impersonation, elevated-privileges

We're trying to run a set of administrative tasks on the server via a web administration console.  The console runs with impersonation as the currently logged-in user, and only administrators on the local machine are allowed to log in.  Right now it works for most cases but we're having trouble when running under UAC.

The first issue is a blocker: it seems like admins do not get the "BUILTIN\Administrators" role even if they are an admin on the local box.  This can prevent them from even getting into the admin console, since we're using the web.config `<allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators">` notation to specify security.  I suspect that the only solutions here are to either run the ASP.NET app as SYSTEM, or to allow more users and do a more granular permissions check in code.  Any other ideas?  Is there any way to inject an elevation request into the built-in ASP.NET permissions check?

The other problem is that we want to run some commands that require administrator access.  The user visiting the site is an administrator, and is correctly impersonated, but when we spawn a process it fails due to lack of administrator privileges.  The clear answer is to elevate for the duration of that command.  There are solutions that will let me temporarily elevate by impersonating a specific username and password, but I'd prefer not to have to ask the already-validated user for his password.  Are there any tricks for elevating the current user?

(I can understand why the ASP.NET team might try to make this hard, so that web pages can't take invisible advantage of an administrator visiting the web site...  but surely there must be some way to pro grammatically declare that your code needs full Administrator rights, appropriately warning the IIS admin of its intentions?)

There are a series of answers for Windows Forms apps, such as:
[How to elevate privileges only when required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required)
and [File.Exists returning false from a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401284/file-exists-returning-false-from-a-network-share)
but I'm hoping to find one that will work with ASP.NET...

Thanks
Steve

Comment: I also have this problem.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: Did you ever use any of the resources I provided in my answer? Or did you take an alternate route?

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for the reminder after all these years :)  When I didn't get any immediate answers in March 2010 I figured it out myself.  I wish I could post the exact way I solved this, but I no longer work at the company so I don't have access to the source code any more (and I'm no longer using .NET)

Comment: If I recall correctly it had to do with "machine administrator" permissions being shadowed, ie. when you impersonate, it strips that part out of your identity token UNLESS you explicitly ask for it to be maintained.  I believe that to make the call & preserve proper credentials, I had to wrap a DLL function rather than using the .NET functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to achieve a "higher" impersonation level from the user currently accessing the website by enabling the server for delegation in Active Directory.  Per Microsoft, `You can think of delegation as a more powerful form of impersonation, as it enables impersonation across a network.`  You may not need to go across the network, but it may resolve your security issues.

Here are a few resources on setting up delegation, hopefully this will help you.

- [Impersonation and Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422858/impersonation-and-delegation)
- [Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517846/impersonation-and-delegation-in-asp-net)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291350(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291350%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (older article)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351#paght000023_delegation